# how to find distance and time calculation between two location in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have multiple locations and current location, i want to find distance between my current location and other given location of google map flutter.

please provide any method or library which can easily calculate time and distance.I am Using this code but i can not find correct distance.

```
double _coordinateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
var p = 0.017453292519943295;
var c = cos;
var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
    c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));}
```

Answer (score 1):

use  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_locations_distance package
add your multiple locations into lat and lon array and use this code

```
for(int i=0;i<locCount;i++){ 
double distance;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  distance = await FlutterLocationsDistance().distanceBetween(currentLat, 
currentLon, lat[i], lon[i]);
} on PlatformException {
  distance = -1.0;
}
}
```

and for each multiple locations you can get the distance between current location and other locations.

to get your current location use https://pub.dev/packages/location package.

for the time you can use https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer package